# using ng-class with angular $scope property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have html structure

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <div style="width:200px; height:200px;background-image:url('img/200x200/{{largeImg}}.png');"
      ng-class="{'magictime foolishIn': 1}">
        <span>
            {{largeImg}}
        </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

using ng-class I want to apply css class to current element which will invoke certain animation on that element [like here](http://minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/)

css class is correctly applied when I look using firebug but animation is not invoked. When  I replace this code with hardcoded values everything works

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px;background-image:url('img/200x200/1.png');"
          ng-class="{'magictime foolishIn': 1}">
            <span>1</span>
       </div>
```

from angularjs I'm using `$scope.largeImg` as property for binding on the view.

Comment: img/200x200/{{largeImg%8}}.png
What is the %8?

Comment: it's typo leftover. fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.myInnerDiv {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   height:200px;background-image:url('img/200x200/{{largeImg % 8}}.png');
}
```

First your content in 'style' property can be a CSS class like above. Also, if you want to trigger animation by adding a CSS class, you can just add it 'class' property like below.

```
<div class="myDiv">
<div class="myInnerDiv magictime foolishIn">
    <span>
        {{largeImg}}
    </span>
```

However, if you want to add it based on a flag, which gets updated by clicking a button, you can use 'ng-class' directive. Look at this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeHawkz/6d4cdwcd/).

**Update: Based on OP's comments. The answer is updated in the JSFiddle**

To achieve your functionality, you need to watch out for changes to your target value. I recommend writing a directive for this, since it is what the directives are for - to manipulate UI.

Comment: thank you for your time but this doesnt work in my code. Whenever $scope.largeImg value is changed css animation doesnt work.

Comment: Ahh! So your question is actually incorrect. Your question should be 'How to trigger an animation whenever I change `$scope.largeImg` value?'

Comment: I updated the answer - check out the last example of the JSFiddle

Comment: Great PasanRatnayake, just one more question, I need to use dynamic image instead of this 3 hardcoded from your directive example.

Comment: Whichever helps you to achieve the functionality you want in your application. Of course, you can move the code in the directive to your controller, then you'd have to duplicate code to make it work. Directives make great re-usable components, if done right.

Also, if you think this is the answer, mark is as the answer, so then thread can close and it will help someone who's looking for the answer too

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px;" 
     ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(img/200x200/{{ largeImg }}.png)'}"
     ng-class="{'magictime foolishIn': 1}">
```

Comment: thank you for your time but this doesnt work in my code. Whenever $scope.largeImg value is changed css animation doesnt work.